# Custom fields in viewmodel based off of model fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I'm fairly new to ASP.NET MVC and need some help.

I have a model called "Project", simplified below:

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjId { get; set; }
    public string StatusID { get; set; }
}
```

The StatusID is a 1 character string, and can be I (In Progress), C (Completed), or K (Killed). So when I get a list of projects from the database, it returns that 1 character status code.

However, when I pass that information to my view, I'd like to show the full description rather than the 1 character.

What's the best way to approach this situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to create a one-to-many relationship with a `Statuses` table. Then create a separate view model with this information.

```
var vm = new ProjectVM
{
    ProjId = project.ProjId,
    StatusDescription = statuses.Find(project.StatusId).Description
};
```

Notices `statuses` is a repository API that finds the right status description.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not sure how to use a repository API but i have another related question.

Since I personally know what the codes stand for, I'm looking to display the full description without the help of another "lookup" table.

Is there no way to use the values of the actual model, and somehow tweak them to add new fields to the passed in view?

As an example, lets say someone wanted to take a model field called "Percent" and append it with a "%" when it's displayed. Is there a way we can add a field called "DisplayPercent" on the fly, that'll take a # and append it with a %?

Comment: You can do all that in Razor code, but to me it feels dirty. You can declare something like an `enum` to display it

Comment: @IsaiahLee, You should be asking a new question, but `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:P}")]public decimal Percent { get; set; }` and `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Percent)` will display `15%` if the value of `Percent` is `0.15`